# cannot go to next interface (android)

Tags: java, android, xml, interface

I'm trying to include some e-mail features in my program. I've created a menu interface for some e-mail features also. So, I have a main menu, and when I click on the e-mail button, I get to the e-mail menu. However, after I click one of the e-mail menu buttons (inbox and send new) program crashes. I've been searching on the internet and have done other menus by using the same implementation method. However, I cannot figure out why I'm getting this error... I'd really appreciate some help, my codes are below:

MainActivity.java where I click on the e-mail button and go to the e-mail menu (Nothing is wrong here, I think):

```
mail_Button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.mailButton);
        mail_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Mail.class);
                //myIntent.putExtra("key", value);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }

        });
```

My mail activity_mail.xml file, where I have two buttons for inbox and send new e-mail:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/inbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="139dp"
        android:text="@string/mail_inbox_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_new"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        android:text="@string/mail_sendnew_button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="@string/mail_main_message"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Inbox.java file where I will do some stuff after I get rid of this problem with your help :)

```
public class Inbox extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_mail_inbox);
        }

}
```

My activity_mail_inbox.xml file where I want to put some stuff(currently empty):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

My SendNew.java file whicj I'm going to use when I'm going to send e-mail:

```
public class SendNew extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_mail_send);
        }

}
```

My activity_mail_send.xml file where I have fields for user to fill and a send button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextViewTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/feedbacktitle"
            android:textSize="10pt"></TextView>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextName"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/feedbackname"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextEmail"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/feedbackemail"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextFeedbackBody"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/feedbackbody"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ButtonSendFeedback"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:onClick="sendFeedback"
            android:text="@string/feedbackbutton" >
</Button>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

So, I cannot reach the two xml files when I click on the buttons and I can't figure out why.

Comment: "program crashes".  Can you provide a stacktrace or any error output?

Comment: I get things like:

11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {gpec.app.metudexter/gpec.app.metudexter.SendNew}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1556)
11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1431)

Comment: 11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3446)
11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3407)
11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3617)
11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3585)
11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609):  at gpec.app.metudexter.Mail$2.onClick(Mail.java:45)

Comment: 11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)
11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17298)
11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)

Comment: And has the activity been declared in your manifest.xml? (perhaps post the manifest.xml)

Comment: 11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
11-06 13:32:28.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6609):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: WOW that's a very good point! I forgot them!

Comment: Edit the question; don't stuff logs into comments. The error message says exactly what's wrong, no?

Answer (score 0):

Above you show code for two activies, `SendNew` and `Inbox`. However, from MainActivity you are trying to go to the `Mail` activity for which there is no code shown. There has to be a class called `Mail` which extends `Activity` and which is declared in your AndroidManifest.xml.  (Or change the code to call the `SendNew` or `Inbox` activities which also must have declarations in the AndroidManifest.xml)